# What's wrong with this simple while loop! (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

```
while (packet[i].source <1 || >1024)
```

> Error: expected primary-expression before > token.

It works fine when I just do `<1` , then when I add an OR operator it breaks :/

inb4 something stupidly simple but I've been coding for days and my brain is on fire.

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
while (packet[i].source < 1 || packet[i].source > 1024)
```

Comment: Since you're new to the site, remember to click the "checkbox" below the rating on the answer to mark this question as "answered."

Answer (score 4):

Something very wrong as it is a syntax error, you have to use:

```
while (packet[i].source <1 || packet[i].source >1024)
```

For every `||` and every `&&` you'll have to refer to `packet[i].source`. Very different from spoken language and might seem like a pain, but you'll learn to love how structured programming is.

Don't worry, we've all been there, it seems it's always the simplest problems that take the longest to fix.

Comment: A shame it's that fundamentally different. Math-like comparisons are so nice. `if (1 > packet[i].source > 1024) {....}`